# ng add @angular/fire@6.1.5 failing to list Firebase projects

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I am trying to hook up an Angular 12 project to firebase and use the firestore functions but the ng add is keeps throwing an error.

to replicate the process I:

1. ng new < new-app >
2. ng add @angular/fire@6.1.5

which popped an error that said run ng add @angular/fire again and when I did this error popped up.

```
$ ng add @angular/fire@6.1.5
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Package information loaded.
 
The package @angular/fire@6.1.5 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Package successfully installed.
UPDATE package.json (1376 bytes)
Skipping installation: Package already installed
UPDATE package.json (1376 bytes)✔ Packages installed successfully.
× Preparing the list of your Firebase projects
Failed to list Firebase projects. See firebase-debug.log for more info.
```

ng v looks like

```
Angular CLI: 12.2.18
Node: 14.17.5
Package Manager: npm 8.13.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 12.2.16
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1202.18
@angular-devkit/build-angular   12.2.18
@angular-devkit/core            12.2.18
@angular-devkit/schematics      12.2.18
@angular/cli                    12.2.18
@angular/fire                   6.1.5
@schematics/angular             12.2.18
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.3.5
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angularfs",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1300",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0 || ^9.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I followed the documentation on the install so why is it throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

For angular version - 12.* ->
install firebase version - 7,8

```
npm i --save firebase@8.2.3
```

install angular fire version - 6.1.5

```
npm i --save @angular/fire@6.1.5
```

Reference - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire